# Checking for duplicate letters within lists by using a histogram function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, histogram

I'm trying to knock out my homework, but having difficulties incorporating the required histogram function.

This is the code I have to work with:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
test_dups = ["zzz","dog","bookkeeper","subdermatoglyphic","subdermatoglyphics"]
test_miss = ["zzz","subdermatoglyphic","the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]

def histogram(s):
     d = dict()
     for c in s:
          if c not in d:
               d[c] = 1
          else:
               d[c] += 1
     return d
```

I need to write a function called `has_duplicates()` that takes a string parameter and returns `True` if the string has any repeated characters. Otherwise, it should return `False`.

Implement `has_duplicates()` by creating a histogram using the `histogram()` function above. Do not use any of the implementations of `has_duplicates()` that are given in your textbook. Instead, your implementation should use the counts in the histogram to decide if there are any duplicates.

Write a loop over the strings in the provided `test_dups` list. Print each string in the list and whether or not it has any duplicates based on the return value of `has_duplicates()` for that string. For example, the output for `aaa` and `abc` would be the following.

```
aaa has duplicates
abc has no duplicates
```

Print a line like one of the above for each of the strings in test_dups.

Write a function called `missing_letters` that takes a string parameter and returns a new string with all the letters of the alphabet that are not in the argument string. The letters in the returned string should be in alphabetical order.

My implementation should use a histogram from the `histogram()` function. It should also use the global variable `alphabet`. It should use this global variable directly, not through an argument or a local copy. It should loop over the letters in `alphabet` to determine which are missing from the input parameter.

The function `missing_letters` should combine the list of missing letters into a string and return that string.

Write a loop over the strings in list test_miss and call `missing_letters` with each string. Print a line for each string listing the missing letters. For example, for the string "aaa", the output should be the following.

aaa is missing letters bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

If the string has all the letters in `alphabet`, the output should say it uses all the letters. For example, the output for the string `alphabet` itself would be the following.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz uses all the letters"
```

Print a line like one of the above for each of the strings in test_miss.

This is as far as I got...

```
def has_duplicates(t):
    if histogram(t) > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Result:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: I realize I'm definitely lacking an understanding of the general concepts here, but if someone could provide some guidance, I'd really appreciate it. Not asking you to complete the assignment for me, because I'd really like to learn how, but how would I start to convert the histogram values into an int so the has_duplicates function executes successfully?

Comment: Have you tested the code they gave you first to see what it returns?

Comment: I'm unsure how you are getting that error. The histogram function you posted returns a `dict`

Comment: IMO you need [edit] your question and reduce the scope of what you're asking because as it stands now, it sounds like you want code for the whole assignment.

Comment: Your histogram returns a dictionary.  You have to loop over the values and check if any  > 1.  (e.g. def has_duplicates(t): return any(v > 1 for k, v in histogram(t).items())

Answer (score 0):

The following should provide the desired result:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
test_dups = ["zzz","dog","bookkeeper","subdermatoglyphic","subdermatoglyphics"]
test_miss = ["zzz","subdermatoglyphic","the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]

def histogram(s):
     d = dict()
     for c in s:
          if c not in d:
               d[c] = 1
          else:
               d[c] += 1
     return d

def has_duplicates(s):
    # Return False if each letter in s is not distinct
    return len(histogram(s)) != len(s)

def missing_letters(s):
    h = histogram(s)
    rv = ''
    # Loop over letters in alphabet, if the letter is not in the histogram then
    # append to the return string.
    for c in alphabet:
        if c not in h:
            rv = rv + c
    return rv

# Loop over test strings as required.
for s in test_miss:
    miss = missing_letters(s)
    if miss:
        print(f"{s} is missing letters {miss}.")
    else:
        print(f"{s} uses all the letters.")
```

**Output:**

```
zzz is missing letters abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy.
subdermatoglyphic is missing letters fjknqvwxz.
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog uses all the letters.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
test_dups = ["zzz", "dog", "bookkeeper", "subdermatoglyphic", "subdermatoglyphics"]
test_miss = ["zzz", "subdermatoglyphic", "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]


def histogram(string):
    d = dict()
    for char in string:
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = 1
        else:
            d[char] += 1
    return d


# Part 1
def has_duplicate(string):
    h = histogram(string)
    for k, v in h.items():
        if v > 1:
            return True
    return False


for string in test_dups:
    if has_duplicate(string):
        print(string, "has duplicates")
    else:
        print(string, "has no duplicates")

# Part 2


def missing_letters(string):
    h = histogram(string)
    new_list = []
    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in h:
            new_list.append(char)
    return "".join(new_list)


for string in test_miss:
    new_list = missing_letters(string)
    if len(new_list):
        print(string, "is missing letters", new_list)
    else:
        print(string, "uses all letters")
```